# Prestashop - list/grid view

Tags: list, view, grid, prestashop

I have a problem with list/grid view on my store: http://vps110594.ovh.net/12-rowery-trekingowe - it doesn't want to switch between views...
I thought that there's problem with js, but after replacing global.js in default bootstrap theme with original file (and adding few of my scripts) it still doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

global.js line 179:

```
$(document).off('mouseleave').on('mouseleave', '.....', function(e){
    if ($('body').find('.container').width() == 1170)
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered')./*css({'height':'auto', '...':'0'})*/;
});
```

You left a dot before commented out section